# Multi Post for Action with return File in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Assume this code in One of my `Action`s

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Generate (Params){

....

InsertOneRawToDB();
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { info = info });

}
```

So every thing is OK yet but when  I change `return` to:

```
InsertOneRawToDB();
byte[] myfile = GenerateAZipFile();
return File( myfile , "application/zip" , "MyFileName");
```

In this case I see a weird behavior: before return, One raw inserted to DB, and after return another raw inserted, it seems the `InsertOneRawToDB` called again.

Does any one know about this? what happening here?

PS: I use Visual Studio 2012 RTM + ASP.NET MVC4

PS: OK I Use IDM (Internet Download Manager) to download zip file and that cause MultiPost on this `Action` So How can I handle this?

Comment: "it seems the InsertOneRawToDB called again."
It seems to me that you don't have a debugger ;)
Tell us if it really is called two times.

Comment: What would you like to achieve? Sinlge insert to Db per user?

Comment: @kubal5003 Who Call `Generate` Action insert One raw to DB and return File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your conclusion that the problem is related to using a download manager... That's what download mangers do.  They create multiple connections to the file.

One thing you could do is store a session variable that says "Already started downloading", and then only insert the record the first time.

however if the user legitimately downloaded the file multiple times then you would only get one record.

Another option would be to examine the Http headers and look for the "Range" header, which is what is used to download a file in multiple pieces (or resume a file).  You would then have to take the Range parameters and only return the portion of the file requested.

Here's an example of how to do a Ranged download: http://tpeczek.com/2011/10/range-requests-in-aspnet-mvc.html

I'm actually quite surprised that this hasn't come up before... I guess most people don't do database actions in a download action or notice it.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to new action and in this new action return file.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Generate (Params){

    ....

    InsertOneRawToDB();
    return RedirectToAction("GetFile"};

}
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetFile
{
    byte[] myfile = GenerateAZipFile();
    return File(myfile, "application/zip", "filename.ext");
}
```

Comment: I try this also, but the Post Action Called Multi Time yet.